# how can I make the Tlist vi plugin to show functions on .lib files?

Tags: vim, vi, tlist

I have a bunch of shell script files with .lib as the name extension and Tlist is not picking up the functions unless the files are renamed using .sh as extension.

How can I have Tlist the .lib files as shell scripts without renaming the files?

Daniel

Comment: Sounds like hard coded. You can modify the source code if you like.

Answer (score 1):

vi was listing the filetype as "cobol" so asking ctgas to treat this filetype as Sh worked for me

Adding the following line to .vimrc did the trick:

```
let tlist_cobol_settings = 'Sh;c:class;f:function'
```

Daniel